# Область видимости переменной в методе Java или ошибка java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, android, область-видимости

Не могу разобраться с областью видимости в Java внутри метода.

```
public class SearchAutoModel {
 public String maker;
  public List<MakerModel> getMakerList ()  {
   makerList   = new ArrayList<>();
    App.getApi().getMakers(2).enqueue(new Callback<List<MakerModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<MakerModel>> call, Response<List<MakerModel>> response) {
            if (response.body() !=null) {
              makerList.addAll(response.body());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<MakerModel>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });

        Log.i("maker",this.makerList.get(0).getMakerName());

  return makerList;
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.
Но если пробовать вывести данные из списка там же, где я добавляю данные в список (сразу после makerList.addAll(response.body()); ), то ошибки нет и значения выводятся.
Я так понимаю, что инициализированный список лежит исключительно в области видимости метода   public void onResponse();
А мне же нужно возвратить список из метода со всеми данными. 
Пробовал делать **this.makerList.addAll(response.body());** , но получается, что это является ошибкой синтаксиса

Comment: В данном случае у вас проблема с пониманием последовательности выполнения, а не областей видимости.

Comment: Как мне тогда обрабатывать ответ от Retrofit 2 ?
То есть каким образом мне наполнить список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, метод API выполняется асинхронно и return срабатывает раньше чем приходит ответ от сервера. Надо сделать синхронный запрос Retrofit.